# Как распарcить свою же html страницу?

Tags: php, laravel

Странный вопрос согласен.

В общем есть поле в которое пользователь вводит текст, но может ввести и смайлики, смайлы подгружаются как картинки. В общем необходимо как-то распарсить этот див на стороне сервера, вытащить текст, вводимый пользователем, и коды смайликов. Может кто что посоветует?

Единственное что я придумал это через jquery сделать скрытый инпут, и при в воде в поле все записывать, но это выглядит геморно может есть более простой путь.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: innerHTML аяксом отправить?

Comment: Если ключевое словое "свою же" - то см. комментарий про innerHTML яксом, если ключевое слово "распарсить" - то делать собственный парсер на основе конечных автоматов. Причём парсить-то можно и не отправляя на сервер, мощь javascript вполне позволяет писать сложные вещи. И ещё: обычно делают обычно два поля. В первом пишут текст, после нажатия кнопки отправки это сообщение рендерится со смайликами в области сообщений. Возможно, будет проще так сделать, чем в одной области и редактировать и отображать. В итоге: о чём вопрос? Обо всём сразу или что-то конкретное непонятно?

Comment: Сделал как выше описали, через  innerHTML